# Android folder execute permissions in Filesystem

Tags: android, android-emulator

hi every one i am creating a Root Directory and sub Directory in **"data/data/com.exp.android/files"** path and downloading xml files in root folder.**root Directory is created but no data displaying in that Directory but i want permission to enter,
run a search through that directory or execute some program from that
directory**
can any one Help me how to give read/write and delete permissions to this Root Directory and Sub Directory,I am Struggling With this problem since 3 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have access to "enter, run a search through that directory or execute some program from that directory" on a production device. You can read and write files to that directory using Java I/O from your own application.